# interface PIC16F877A with SIM900A GSM module

Tags: c, gsm, sim900, proteus

I've tried to interface PIC16F877A with SIM800l V2.2 in order to send sensor data from the microcontroller. While connecting SIM800L with proteus using TTL connection all the data are sent through GSM as we expected. But while we upload the code to the PIC16F877A, there is no response from the GSM module. I've also checked the baud rate, Tx and Rx configuration, changed the PIC16F877A but we can't obtain the results. I also changed the GSM module to SIM900A but still it's not working. Is there anyone who can help me with this issue please.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlbsy.jpg)

Comment: I suggest you should post your question here: [electronics.stackexchange.com](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) To give a brief note, have you checked that you SIM800/SIM900 is powered correctly? Minimal voltage and current should be 3.8V/2.5A. Noise on Tx/Rx bus is also another thing to care.

Comment: Check the actual data lines using an oscilloscope or logic analyser. There aren't enough details in your question for anyone to answer it: we can't tell if your code is wrong without seeing it, we can't tell if your hardware connection is wrong without seeing it (or at least a schematic). However, troubleshooting hardware is off-topic here.

Comment: Here I attached my code can you please check it. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1zmLmZsdXal8a18pFbxbpuaNUC2IYvD7boOROaATMfuU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I've provided the enough power supply, it's not the problem. I've also checked with an oscilloscope I've obtain a response from the GSM module, but the PIC16f877a is not receiving it I guess